# SQL Selecting from multiple tables

Tags: sql, selection

I have four tables `Student`,`Enrolment`,`Building`,`Campus` and their fields are as:

Student:

- StudentID
- Name
- Level

Enrolment:

- Ref
- StudentID
- Course
- EnrolDate
- Building_ID

Building:

- BuildingID
- BuildingName
- CampusID

Campus:

- CampusID
- CampusName

I need `Name` of students who are enrolled and studying at the `CampusName` = 'City Centre'. I tried numerous things but because it needs multiple connections to different tables I got really confused.

Thank you

Comment: Show what you've tried so far.

Comment: `SELECT ... FROM ... INNER JOIN  ... WHERE CampusName = 'City Centre'...` You're basically asking for someone to write the query rather than help you with the problem. You will get more responses if you display what you've already tried and the problems experienced. See [This Useful Guide on how to ask questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: Also which type of database are you dealing with? SQL Server? Oracle? MySQL?

Comment: @talegna - I don't think the DB type matters for this question -- simple joins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
SELECT S.Name
FROM Student S
INNER JOIN Enrolment E ON S.StudentID = E.StudentID
INNER JOIN Building B ON E.Building_ID = B.BuildingID
INNER JOIN Campus C ON C.CampusID = B.CampusID
WHERE C.CampusName = 'City Centre'
```

Comment: nice try, but it is `E.Building_ID` in the question

Comment: @Hogan I assumed that it was a typo as it didn't follow the naming convention used for the other fields; i changed my query anyway.

Comment: It probably was a typo -- I was being a dork.

Answer (score 0):

Just do the joins in order -- left to right:

```
SELECT *
FROM Student S
JOIN Enrolment E ON E.StudentID = S.StudentID
JOIN Building B ON B.BuildingID = E.Building_ID
JOIN Campus C ON C.CampusID = B.CampusID
WHERE C.CampusName = 'City Centre'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT S.* 
FROM Students S INNER JOIN
Enrolment E ON E.StudentID=S.StudentID INNER JOIN
Building B ON B.BuildingID= E.Building_ID INNER JOIN
Campus C ON C.CampusID=E.CampusID
WHERE CampusName = 'City Centre'
```